# How can a subsection in a self-generated ToC contain another subsection in Asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

For my Asciidoc file I'm setting up a Table of Contents which must contain different sections that are filled with subsections. These subsections also contain some subsections themselves. How can I set it up somehow that my table of contents won't just contain one set of subsections?

With using Asciidoc auto ToC generator `:toc:` (`toc -a` in terminal) and the auto section number generator `:sectnums:`, I have generated a ToC that contains one set of subsection for each section. I have used different levels of `=` to make the ToC generator understand which are sections, which are subsections and... But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work

```
:sectnums:

==section1

(some table)

===subsection A

(some table)

====subsection B

(some table)

====subsection C

(some table)

=====subsection D

(some table)

===subsection E

==section2
...
```

What I need to be generated as a result is something like this:

```
1. section1
 1.1. subsection A
  1.1.1. subsection B
  1.1.2. subsection C
   1.1.2.1. subsection D
 1.2. subsection E
2. section2
```

All I get so far is like this:

```
1. section1
 1.1. subsection A
 1.2. subsection B
 1.3. subsection C
 1.4. subsection D
 1.5. subsection E
2. section2
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in TOC macro defaults to 2 levels of sections. You can adjust the levels like so:

```
:toclevels: 5
```

For more details, see: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-toc-levels

Note: Make sure that your Asciidoctor document includes a top-level title, page-level attributes should be specified immediately after the top-level title, and section titles should have a space immediately following the equals signs. Like so:

```
= Document
:sectnums:
:toc:
:toclevels: 5

== section1

(some table)

...
```